# Are socket.io SERVER emit callbacks blocking?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

When an emit is received on the SERVER (i.e. generated by a client), does the callback function complete before the next emit is processed?

Example:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    log('disconnect START - ' + socket.id);

    ...
    ...
    Do some stuff
    ...
    ...

    log('disconnect END - ' + socket.id);
});
```

I seem to be getting this output in my log:

```
disconnect START - z0w0W4scKZ8o6c4nAAAm
disconnect END - z0w0W4scKZ8o6c4nAAAm
disconnect START - LLnSgRBV9NZ35mjrAAAk
disconnect START - djl3hyNvIwAhSEDbAAAn
disconnect END - LLnSgRBV9NZ35mjrAAAk
disconnect END - djl3hyNvIwAhSEDbAAAn
```

As you can see, a START interrupts another before the END is reached...

Comment: _If_ _"Do some stuff"_ does some async activities..

Comment: What are 'async activities'?

Comment: Anything which is executed asynchronously....

Comment: Yes, but how do I know what is being done asynchronously?  The code in 'Do stuff' is just manipulating arrays and sending more emits to clients...?

Answer (score 2):

Socket.io sticks to the basic principal of event loop based asynchronous code execution,where each of your **emit** and **on** callbacks get executed when the event with specific name has been emitted and/or listened.

And since these are events there is no surety of sequential execution unless otherwise such arrangements are made in code itself

```
  //Server
  //1. Emit this event
  socket.emit('First_Event', { hello: 'world' });

  //2. Listen to this event 
  socket.on('Synchronous-Event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });

  //Client
  //1. Listen to this event
  socket.on('First_Event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    //2.Then emit this event
    socket.emit('Synchronous-Event', { my: 'data' });
  });
```

The above code ensures  that the **'Synchronous-Event'** event on client side executes after the **'First_Event'** is listened by client.

Also note that the event 1 & 2 can be executed in any order no matter their calling sequence on client side.

```
 //For Example **alternate** asynchronous event
 //Client
      //1. Listen to this event
      socket.on('First_Event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
      //2.Emit this event async*
      socket.emit('Synchronous-Event', { my: 'data' });
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback function is invoked everytime the on() is invoked.

NodeJS runs asynchronously and is non-blocking I/O. Thus when the 3rd START is finished processing, the respective END is expected on the console.

But Node.JS jumps ahead the code, as the END is still processing, to invoke the callback and print the next START on the console and when the END which was waiting is finished processing, it is displayed on the console.

```
1 disconnect START - z0w0W4scKZ8o6c4nAAAm
1 disconnect END - z0w0W4scKZ8o6c4nAAAm
2 disconnect START - LLnSgRBV9NZ35mjrAAAk
3 disconnect START - djl3hyNvIwAhSEDbAAAn
2 disconnect END - LLnSgRBV9NZ35mjrAAAk
3 disconnect END - djl3hyNvIwAhSEDbAAAn
```

Comment: Yes. If you want to control the flow in your code then you have to.

Comment: What blocking locks can I use in JavaScript?

Comment: I doubt this will somehow break the code.. What issue you are facing ? How could one block it ? Not allowing other users to use `socket` ? That is very bad option I reckon...

Comment: @lombrozo you can use process.nextTick(). Refer to this [link](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_arg)